# SpringBoot does not find my dependency in BOOT-INF/lib/ folder

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I can run a springBoot APP using the IDE or `mvn spring-boot:run` perfectly, but I cannot when I do:

```
java -jar myapp-0.1.jar
```

PS.: I'm Embedding myproject-0.1 into digitalizacao-sender-0.0.1.jar

Cause I got an error saying

```
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File [/home/myuser/workspace/digitalizacao-sender/target/digitalizacao-sender-0.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/myproject-0.1.jar] referenced by given URL [file:/home/myuser/workspace/digitalizacao-sender/target/digitalizacao-sender-0.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/myproject-0.1.jar] does not exist
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:73) ~[myproject-0.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.buildArchiveDescriptor(StandardArchiveDescriptorFactory.java:48) ~[myproject-0.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.buildArchiveDescriptor(AbstractScannerImpl.java:95) ~[myproject-0.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:70) ~[myproject-0.1.jar!/:na]
    ... 20 common frames omitted . But I can see my dependency (another jar project) inside `BOOT-INF/lib/`
```

Follow a piece of my `pom.xml`:

```
<project>    
  ...
  <artifactId>digitalizacao-sender</artifactId>
  ...   
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.my.organization</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>   <--- my dependency
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Anyone have an idea, why I cannot run `java -jar`.

Comment: Could you extend the "blablabla" a little more please? The exact type of the error that you get is relevant.

Comment: I already updated it. Any doubts ask me.

Comment: is it building up proper fat jar?

Comment: @ShashiShankar yes. My dependency is inside the jar file in the dir /BOOT-INF/lib/myproject-1.0.jar